# How do I serialize (NewtonSoft) a class that includes an interface with a property named Type?

Tags: .net, jsonconvert, adyen

I need to serialize a result of this class (Assembly Adyen, Version=6.0.0.0):

```
<Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute>
Public Class PaymentResponse
    Implements IEquatable(Of PaymentResponse), IValidatableObject

    Public Sub New(...)

    ...
   <Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Name:="action", EmitDefaultValue:=False)>
    Public Property Action As IPaymentResponseAction

    ...        

End Class
```

Looking at the result, I have Action.PaymentData, Action.PaymentMethodType, Action.Token, Action.[Type] and Action.Url as expected:
[Screenshot of Autos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8TyP.png)

But when I serialize the result,

```
Dim tmp As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ret, GetType(PaymentResponse), New 
                     Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() With {.[Error] = AddressOf jsonerror})
```

I only get:

```
{
  "resultCode": "IdentifyShopper",
  "action": {
  "paymentData": "XXX",
  "paymentMethodType": "scheme",
  "token": "YYY"
},
"authentication": {
"threeds2.fingerprintToken": "ZZZ"
},
"details": [
 {
  "key": "threeds2.fingerprint",
  "type": "text"
 }
],
"paymentData": "QQQ"
}
```

I'm not getting Action.[Type] and "Action.Url" in my Json string.

```
jsonerror()
```

is never hit.

EDIT: I added a tracewriter:

```
Dim tracewriter As Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ITraceWriter = New 
                      Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.MemoryTraceWriter
Dim tmp As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ret, 
                      GetType(PaymentResponse), New 
                      Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() With 
                     {.TraceWriter = tracewriter, .[Error] = AddressOf 
                        jsonerror})
```

And everything looks fine, except I'm not getting the action.[type] serialized:

> 2021-01-19T14:25:11.852 Info Started serializing
> Adyen.Model.Checkout.PaymentResponse. Path ''. 2021-01-19T14:25:11.854
> Info Started serializing
> Adyen.Model.Checkout.PaymentResponse+ResultCodeEnum with converter
> Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter. Path 'resultCode'.
> 2021-01-19T14:25:11.854 Info Finished serializing
> Adyen.Model.Checkout.PaymentResponse+ResultCodeEnum with converter
> Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter. Path 'resultCode'.
> 2021-01-19T14:25:11.856 Info Started serializing
> Adyen.Model.Checkout.Action.CheckoutThreeDS2FingerPrintAction. Path
> 'action'. 2021-01-19T14:25:11.857 Info Finished serializing
> Adyen.Model.Checkout.Action.CheckoutThreeDS2FingerPrintAction. Path
> 'action'. 2021-01-19T14:25:11.857 Info Started serializing
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]. Path 'authentication'. 2021-01-19T14:25:11.857 Info Finished serializing System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String].
> Path 'authentication'. 2021-01-19T14:25:11.857 Info Started
> serializing
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Adyen.Model.Checkout.InputDetail]. Path 'details'. 2021-01-19T14:25:11.857 Info Started serializing Adyen.Model.Checkout.InputDetail. Path 'details'. 2021-01-19T14:25:11.857 Info Finished serializing Adyen.Model.Checkout.InputDetail. Path 'details[0]'. 2021-01-19T14:25:11.857 Info Finished serializing System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Adyen.Model.Checkout.InputDetail].
> Path 'details'. 2021-01-19T14:25:11.860 Info Finished serializing
> Adyen.Model.Checkout.PaymentResponse. Path ''. 2021-01-19T14:25:11.860
> Verbose Serialized JSON:  {   "resultCode": "IdentifyShopper",
> "action": {
> "paymentData": "XXX",
> "paymentMethodType": "scheme",
> "token": "YYY"   },   "authentication": {
> "threeds2.fingerprintToken": "ZZZ"   },   "details": [
> {
> "key": "threeds2.fingerprint",
> "type": "text"
> }   ],   "paymentData": "QQQ" }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the Adyen .NET library. The implementation classes for `IPaymentResponseAction` is missing `DataMember` annotations. There is a [fix](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-dotnet-api-library/pull/367/files) ready to be merged and will be available in the next patch release soon. I suggest you update to the patch version when released.

For the URL field, it will be available only for certain actions like redirect, like for ideal payment method. FOr scheme, as in your case, URL is not applicable.